# LINQ query with GROUP BY and Count(*) into Anonymous Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, group-by, anonymous-types

I'm trying to use a LINQ query to determine how many of each particular object type I have and record those values into an anonymous type.

Let's say I have some data that looks like this (there are really objects exposing this property, but it'll work the same)

```
GroupId
1
1
2
2
2
3
```

I know how to format my query in SQL.  It would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT grp = GroupId, cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY GroupId
```

In this case the output would be something like [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef3427/1):

```
GroupID  Count
1        2
2        3
3        1
```

How can I do the same thing with LINQ in vb.net

```vb
Dim groupCounts = From person In data
                  Group By person.GroupId
                  Select new {group = person.GroupId, count = count(*)}
```

That's not quite right, but I think it's close.

Also, not knowing much about anonymous types, can I actually declare `groupCounts` ahead of time that it will be an enumeration of items which each have a group and count property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this in LinqPad, and subbing out for your database entity it should get you closer.

```
Public Sub grouper2()
    Dim numbers = New Integer() {1,1,2,2,2,3}

    Dim numberGroups = From w In numbers _
                    Group w By Key = w Into Group _
                    Select Number = Key, numbersCount = Group.Count()

    'linqpad specific output
    'numberGroups.Dump()

    For Each g In numberGroups
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers that match '{0}':", g.Number)
            Console.WriteLine(g.numbersCount)        
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm used to C#:

```
var query = from person in data
            group person by person.GroupId into grouping
            select new { Key = grouping.Key, Count = grouping.Count() }
```

But I have tested the following snippet in VB and it works:

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles (Path.GetTempPath()).Take (100).ToArray().AsQueryable()

Dim groups = From f In files Group f By key = Path.GetExtension (f) Into Group
             Select Key = key, NumberGroup = Group.Count()
```

Answer (score 2):

So vb is a bit odd when it comes to translating this syntax.  It seems that you can only insert groups `into` an element titled exactly "`Group`".  This then exposes the rest of the grouping functionality

```
From person In data
Group person By grpId = person.GroupId Into Group
Select id = grpId, count = Group.Count
```