# c# calculate distinct value in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, data-manipulation

what i have in my datatable

```
Resource

   1           // 1 represent normal
   1
   2           // 2 represent sql
   2
   3           // 3 css
   4           // 4 unicode
   4
   4
```

how can i perform calculation so that i could display the value in a textbox

```
normal     2
sql        2
css        1
unicode    3

total hits 9
```

what ive tried so far

```
var result = my_datatable.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Resource"]));
string result2 = result.ToString();
totalTxtBox.Text = result2;
```

but it calculate the whole column (output is: 24 instead of 9)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query with GROUP BY and Count(\*) into Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489405/linq-query-with-group-by-and-count-into-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Distinct()`

`var result = my_datatable.AsEnumerable().Distinct().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Resource"]));`

Distinct() Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

You can try to use this example as your reference. Firstly, I get the Distinct values from the datatable and converted it to list and then use the sum function.

**Updated Answer:**

```
 DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();
 my_datatable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
 my_datatable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));

 my_datatable.Rows.Add(1, "Normal");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(1, "Normal");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(2, "SQL");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(2, "SQL");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(3, "CSS");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(4, "UNICODE");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(4, "UNICODE");
 my_datatable.Rows.Add(4, "UNICODE");

 var distinctIds = my_datatable.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(s => new {
                   value = s.Field<int>("value"),
               })
               .Distinct().ToList();


  int total = distinctIds.Sum(item => item.value);
```

Comment: I still got the same output which is 2. Anyway thanks for your reply, i'll do some research about that.

Comment: I finally got the answer (total hits = 9). The only problem now is how can i calculate each one of them. I mean is there any way i can classify all those type/select the value. Cause i need to display them in a textbox separately. (Possibly something like : get datatable column "Resource" where value = "2" (so the output will be 2). I hope you get my idea... thank you for your reply.

Comment: You mean by there will be an input box for "Resource" when the user input "2" the result will be the total hits of "2"?

Comment: Great. Can you share us your solution? So that it will benefit the others too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example-

```
int[] res = { 1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4};

var words = res.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x);

foreach (var x in words)
 {
Console.WriteLine(x.Key+"-"+x.Count());
 }
```

It will print output as-

```
1-2
2-2
3-1
4-3
```

Comment: Make changes accordingly in ur code.I tried it in an array just for demo purpose.you should do  my_datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Resource"])) and then print the key and count to check.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I will try soon since my workspace is at the office. Anyway, my situation is that those resource are currently in my datatable after it goes thru discretion process. So is it possible to use linq to do the calculation seperately base on the value itself? I mean directly from the column cause i need to display back the value in a textbox for each one of them. Hope you get the idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself

use this line (linq) in order to filter out which value you want

```
        int normalcount = my_datatable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Resource") == "1")
            .Count();
```

try to change this line to filter out which value, according to your column value

```
         .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Resource") == "2")
         .Count();
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped out to answer this as well.